# Using an ArrayList as a stack to validate pairs of elements (getting an anomolous result)

Tags: java, arraylist, stack

The following Boolean method determines (99% of the time!) whether a given string consisting of various brackets is 'balanced', ie. that brackets so ordered would constitute a valid syntactical arrangement. The brackets are fed into an ArrayList individually, with the ArrayList then functioning as a stack, removing valid pairs as they appear at the end of the list. An empty list then returns true, signalling a 'balanced' arrangement.

My question is, why does the following 'unbalanced' input...

( [ ] ) ( { ) }

return true?

I'd really appreciate it if somebody would take the time to understand the problem.

```
public static boolean isBalanced(String e) {
    char a[] = e.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<Character> b = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
       b.add(a[i]);
       while (b.size() >= 2 && ((b.get(b.size()-2)=='(' && b.get(b.size()-1)==')') || (b.get(b.size()-2)=='[' && b.get(b.size()-1)==']') || (b.get(b.size()-2)=='{' && b.get(b.size()-1)=='}'))){
           b.remove(b.size()-2);
           b.remove(b.size()-1);
        }             
        if (b.isEmpty()){
            return true;
        }
    }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use integer literals to represent characters? Use character literals (`'{'` and `'}'` instead of `123` and `125`, for example).

Comment: I assume that after you push `( [ ] )` to your stack (which is balanced), your stack becomes empty and you return `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because after checking `( [ ] )` ie. `i=3` condition `b.isEmpty()` is true.

change condition to this:

```
if (b.isEmpty() && i == a.length - 1) {
    return true;
}
```